# In data.table, How can I subset with ifelse() in j and use .N as the number of observations after the subset?

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

I have a data table where I subset using a `ifelse()` command of the `j` part of the data table. I want to count the number of observations inside this subset (not the entire observation of the group). If I used the `i` part, no problem:

```
library("data.table")
set.seed(1234)
testdata <- data.table(x= rnorm(10),
                   id= rep(c("a","b"), each =5))


testdata[x > 0, newvari := .N, by= id] 
testdata

          x id newvari
 1: -1.2071  a      NA
 2:  0.2774  a       3
 3:  1.0844  a       3
 4: -2.3457  a      NA
 5:  0.4291  a       3
 6:  0.5061  b       1
 7: -0.5747  b      NA
 8: -0.5466  b      NA
 9: -0.5645  b      NA
10: -0.8900  b      NA
```

However, if I use `j`, the group is determined by its total size (most likely since I didn't subset in `i` and `.N` still counts there).

```
          x id newvari newvarj
 1: -1.2071  a      NA      NA
 2:  0.2774  a       3       5
 3:  1.0844  a       3       5
 4: -2.3457  a      NA      NA
 5:  0.4291  a       3       5
 6:  0.5061  b       1       5
 7: -0.5747  b      NA      NA
 8: -0.5466  b      NA      NA
 9: -0.5645  b      NA      NA
10: -0.8900  b      NA      NA
```

Is there a way to get newvari using an `ifelse()` statement in `j`?

edit: There were very important reasons for me to subset in `j` that I can't exactly recall right now. Suffice it to say that my actual code is so messy that I'd love to not have to take it apart again. ;) And this might be useful for others in the future as well I hope, just as an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method of reproducing `newvari`. You could use `ifelse()` but `fifelse()` is its `data.table` version.

```
testdata[, newvarj := fifelse(x > 0, sum(x > 0), NA_real_), by = id]
```

Comment: interesting, thanks! Its not quite as flexible as .N though, right? Something like `testdata[, newvarj := fifelse(x > 0, 1:sum(x > 0), NA_real_), by = id]` wont work here. Do you know why?

Comment: @PeterPan It wouldn't work to have "Yes" that is longer than the test in the ifelse statement.